# Which test is the best I can use

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I want to find out whether two groups of people (with and without Autism) differ in their interpretation of ironic compliments and ironic criticisms.
To this end I did a study with (26?) persons without autism and (?) persons with autism. All participants  first had to read 10 stories, with a remark at the end that could be ironic or literal. After each story, 3 questions were asked about the story (Q1 = identification of the speakers meaning, Q2 = control question, Q3 = recognizing the speakers' emotion). So they had to fill in 30 questions.

For each question and group, I calculated ratio of correct answers to all answers from that question and group. Then I applied a Mann-Whitney U test to these ratios, separately for each question type (Q1, Q2, Q3), to see if there are differences between the 2 groups when interpreting all the Q1's, all the Q2's and all the Q3's. I am not sure if this is the correct way to analyze the data - should I do something completely different?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi Carlijn, I have edited your question quite heavily to make it more easy to see the most relevant information for potential answerers :-) I have also removed the tag "corpus-linguistics" because I don't think it is important for the answer and will deter people that are not specialist in that but could answer. Also, you did not ask about R here.
Could you please add information about the number of participants in each group, and whether all answers were answered? And try to check if you are still happy with the question in the new form (I will take the changes back otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

I would do logistic regression on Q3 (which is the one you seem interested in). That would let you add covariates, which you probably should do (e.g. age, sex, education ...)